# How to cast an object to its concrete type automatically without explcitly checking its type in C#?

Tags: c#, casting

Here is simple form of what I use write now.

```
public class Connectable {
    public List<A> connectedA;
    public List<B> connectedB;

    public void Connectable()
    {
        connectedA = new List<A>();
        connectedB = new List<B>();
    }

    public void AddConnection(Connectable otherConnectable)
    {
        if (otherConnectable is A) {
            A a = (A)otherConnectable;
            connectedA.Add(a);
        }
        else if (otherConnectable is B) {
            B b = (B)otherConnectable;
            connectedB.Add(b);
        }
    }
}

public class A : Connectable {
}

public class B : Connectable {
}
```

Is there a way I can improve AddConnection function by autocasting it or something?

I am looking for a way to replace it with:

```
public void AddConnection(A a){
    connectedA.Add(a);
}

public void AddConnection(B b){
    connectedB.Add(b);
}
```

and using it via autocast keyword, if something like that exists.

```
A a=new A();
B b=new B();
A.AddConnection(autocast B);
B.AddConnection(autocast A);
```

Please provide any other advice on improving my current code if it is a bad design.

Update: I should mention that I wanted to maintain 2 seperate Lists in each class i.e, class A will have list of A and B and class B will also have lists of A and B. Given, pairs of AA, AB, BA OR BB, they get added to each others List.
I use them in a game engine. The logic is A reacts with it's connected As and Bs in different ways. The same goes for B. It too reacts with it's connected A and B.

Also, that class name was IConnectable because I initially used an interface then changed it to class. Fixed it now. Nothing more than a typo.

So far, using OfType along with single List (@patrick-magee answer) seems to best match with what I am looking for.

Comment: `IConnectable` isn't a good name for class, `I` prefix is used with interfaces. If `A` and `B` classes store a lists with itself type and it's known a runtime, why just don't move `AddConnection` to `A` and `B`

Comment: I would use the keyword _as_ instead of _is_

Comment: Also, the code will not compile, constuctor can't have a return type. There is also no `autocast` in C#, you can have a look at generics

Comment: @Steve Do tell how exactly should I use _as_ operator.

Comment: autocast keyword was just there for illustration purpose there incase something similar existed. I am well aware it doesn't exist in C#. Also, class name was a typo.

Comment: Because you are casting to the type when the if condition is true then you could write _A testA = otherConnectable as A; if(testA != null) connectedA.Add(testA);_ and this will remove the cast line inside the if block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends what you are really trying to achieve. But you could have 1 collection type, and then to retrieve the child types, you could do something like this:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var connectable = new Connectable();

    connectable.AddConnection(new ConnectableA());
    connectable.AddConnection(new ConnectableB());

    var connectableAs = connectable.GetConnected<ConnectableA>();
    var connectableBs = connectable.GetConnected<ConnectableB>();   
}

public class Connectable
{
    private List<Connectable> connected;

    public Connectable()
    {       
        connected = new List<Connectable>();
    }

    public void AddConnection(Connectable connectable)
    {
        this.connected.Add(connectable);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Connectable> GetConnected<T>() where T : Connectable
    {
        return this.connected.OfType<T>();
    }
}

public class ConnectableA : Connectable
{

}

public class ConnectableB : Connectable
{

}
```

Comment: I updated my question. But, your answer seems to closest match my requirements. I will accept it after some time.

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine:

```
public void AddConnection(A a){
    connectedA.Add(a);
}

public void AddConnection(B b){
    connectedB.Add(b);
}

// ...

A a=new A();
B b=new B();
a.AddConnection(b);
b.AddConnection(a);
```

What you probably meant is this:

```
Connection c1 = GetConnection(/* some arguments */);
Connection c2 = GetConnection(/* some arguments */);
c1.AddConnection(c2); //error: no suitable overload (or something like that)
```

Here is where your "autocast" would come in handy, but AFAIK there is no such thing. What you can do is use a trick that is used in double dispatch, but you only need one part of the dispatch:

```
public abstract class Connectable {
    public List<A> connectedA;
    public List<B> connectedB;

    public void Connectable()
    {
        connectedA = new List<A>();
        connectedB = new List<B>();
    }

    public void AddConnection(Connectable otherConnectable)
    {
        otherConnectable.AddTo(this);
    }

    public abstract void AddTo(Connectable otherConnectable);
}

public class A: Connectable {
    public override void AddTo(Connectable otherConnectable)
    {
        otherConnectable.connectedA.add(this);
    }
}

public class B: Connectable {
    public override void AddTo(Connectable otherConnectable)
    {
        otherConnectable.connectedB.add(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat. But adding to otherConnectible seems a bit hacky. Maybe it's just me. Anyways, nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs a lot of improvements and fixes, in design and implementation.
But let's ignore it for the sake of explanation. 
Because you are inheriting from `Connectable` (changed IConnectable to Connectable - **I**-some class name... is a convention for Interface and this is a class - do not use **I** if it's not an Interface).

All the derived classes (`A` and `B`) are also `Connectable` because it's their base class, hence you can use [virtual methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) and [polymorphism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism), please read comments in this example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Connectable obj = new Connectable();
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        obj.AddConnection(a);
        obj.AddConnection(b);

        // show to console
        obj.ShowObjects();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}

// change IConnectable to Connectable - I is a convention for Interface and it is a class
public class Connectable
{
    // the list will be the base class (Connectable), all derived clasess (A,B) are also Connectable because they inherits Connectable
    public List<Connectable> connectedAANDB;

    public Connectable()
    {
        connectedAANDB = new List<Connectable>();
    }

    public void AddConnection(Connectable otherConnectable)
    {
        connectedAANDB.Add(otherConnectable);
    }

    // virtual method to override in each derived class in order to show the class name
    public virtual string WhoAmI()
    {
        return "I AM Connectable";
    }

    public void ShowObjects()
    {
        foreach (Connectable itm in connectedAANDB)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(itm.WhoAmI());
        } 
    }
}


public class A: Connectable
{
    public override string WhoAmI()
    {
        return "I AM A";
    }
}

public class B: Connectable
{
    public override string WhoAmI()
    {
        return "I AM B";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do tell what other improvements and fixes you suggest. Also, I updated my question.